# Laravel - Tinker breakpoint in controller

Tags: laravel, php-7, laravel-8, tinker, psysh

New to Lavarel.

I am trying to debug a controller's method in Laravel, to do so I'm using Tinker (which is based on Psysh).

I added both of these versions to the breakpoint inside the method **signup** of my **MySuperController**:

```
extract(\Psy\Shell::debug(get_defined_vars()));
eval(\Psy\sh());
```

I've run `php artisan tinker` and done the following in the console:

```
$controller = app()->make('\App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\MySuperController');
app()->call([$controller, 'signup'], ["param"=>"value"]);
```

When executing that, Tinker responds with: ***Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException with message 'The given data was invalid.'***

But I never see the code stop on the breakpoint. Did I assume wrongly that I could debug step by step with Tinker?

Comment: are you using a form request to validate? if so they are resolved and validated before your controller method is called

Comment: hey @lagbox , there doesn't seem to be one. There's a route, it points directly to a controller and the method. I'll keep on searching though. I don't see any $request->validated() called yet.

Comment: hey @lagbox, you were absolutely right, can you post it as an answer? the method was using a custom request class, which extended from an abstract one, which extended from api/application/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/FormRequest.php . I added the eval() within that class and it finally got to the breakpoint. Awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer was based off of user @lagbox's comment. I asked them to make it an answer so I could choose it, but it's been 4 months, so I'm creating it myself so others can quickly see the question has been answered:

User @lagbox mentioned in a comment:

> are you using a form request to validate? if so they are resolved and validated before your controller method is called

The comment was spot on.  Tmethod was using a **custom request class**, which extended from **api/application/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/FormRequest.php** . I added the `eval()` within that class and it finally got to the **breakpoint**.